# 1.9 CMS Static blocks different style from CMS Pages

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cms, static-block

Viewing a cms page, It uses
 skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css
 when I copy and paste the same CMS page content in a static block for category view,
 the styles are rendered differently from the CMS page style.css that i wanted

I checked
 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/block.php
 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/page.php
Both are 100% identical

I also checked 
 app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
 app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/1column.phtml

Static block - Incorrect style format https://eliteshoppercentral.com/about.html

CMS Page - Correct style format https://eliteshoppercentral.com/about-us/

Styles.css doesn't apply to static blocks like it does with pages.
I have 260ms load time, other methods sacrifice performance or add redundant pages to my cache.
What can be done to have static blocks display clean like the CMS page?

Comment: Can you be more specific what is you problem?. Correct me if I'm wrong but you are showing a static context throw a category view bc you page is included in the top menu correct?. You are saying if you show the same page throw a cms page you correctly see the content

Comment: unable to understand question update your question.

Comment: @GrinGo Yes, precisely. In cms page view the content is displayed the way I designed it. However, when viewing the same exact content(copy+paste) through a static block in category view it ignores the style in skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RWD has custom styles applied only to cms pages, look at `skin/frontend/rwd/default/scss/module/_cms.scss` and you'll find it.
I've seen that you are using the static block in a category view, to have the same styles add `catalog-category-view` to `_cms.scss` and recompile scss files.

Now you have:

```
.cms-page-view,
.cms-no-route {
...
```

and it should become:

```
.cms-page-view,
.cms-no-route,
.catalog-category-view {
...
```